# objects not visible after re-login in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, h2

I have simple spring boot app, which have a page to add some notes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3BKS.png)
As long as I am login I can see it but when I log out and login again I don't until I add the new note.
**How to make those objects visible directly after re-login?**

I am using H2 DB and my SpringSecurtity config looks like this:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup","/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll().
    anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();

    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true);
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

    http.csrf().disable(); // in order to log into h2 console in browser
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // in order to log into h2 console in browser
}
```

HTML file for Notes handling:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-notes" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-notes-tab">
                    <button id="add-new-note-button" style="margin: 0.25em;" type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" onclick="showNoteModal()">
                        + Add a New Note
                    </button>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped" id="userTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th style="width: 60%" scope="col">Description</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="note : ${notes}">
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <th scope="row" th:text="${note.noteTitle}">Example Note Title</th>
                                    <td th:text="${note.noteDescription}">Example Note Description </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="noteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="noteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="noteModalLabel">Note</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form action="#" th:object="${noteForm}" th:action="@{/home}" method="POST">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="noteId" id="note-id">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="note-title" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
                                            <input type="text" field="*{noteTitle}" name= "noteTitle" class="form-control" id="note-title" maxlength="20" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="note-description" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" field="*{noteDescription}" name="noteDescription" id="note-description" rows="5" maxlength="1000" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <button id="noteSubmit" type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button id="note-save-changes" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#noteSubmit').click();">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The reason for not dispplaying objects after re-login was the controller class - it didn't load needed data:

missing part in Controller class was loading data from the model:

```
model.addAttribute("notes", noteService.getUserNotes(userId));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).